# Android Integrating Firebase Messaging in Library Module

Tags: firebase, push-notification, android-library

I am implementing a **Android Library Module** which will be given as .jar / .aar to other parties. One of the features I am trying to include is **Firebase Push Notifications** into library.

But as there would no applicationId for a library project, I really couldn't find a way to integrate Firebase into my module (In order to download google-services.json, we need applicationId or package name, google-playservices in .gradle).

Please suggest me if there is any other workaround regarding this.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

*Firebaser here*

Firebase features are integrated at the level of the entire app, not on a per-module or per-library basis.  What you are trying to do is not a supported use case.

Comment: Oh I see. Can I create a normal project integrating firebase and then export that as library project by changing the apply plugin: 'com.android.application' to apply plugin: 'com.android.library' ?

Comment: I don't think that's going to work.  Application modules build an APK, library modules build an AAR, to be merged into another APK.

Comment: @Minion Yes, that is the use case I am exploring. Is there any solution

Comment: @Akshay I moved the config to main project only as I couldn't achive it in library project